# Multiple plots in python creates error message "Can not reset the axes"

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot two plots, side by side, comparing kappa for training and test sets.

Here's the working code to make one such plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotKappa(train_kappa,test_kappa):
    objects = ('train', 'test')
    y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
    performance = [train_kappa,test_kappa]

    plt.bar(y_pos, performance, align='center', alpha=0.5)
    plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
    plt.ylabel('kappa')
    plt.title('kappa training vs test')

plotKappa(0.9 ,0.2)
```

which results in this plot:

[image: one plot]

I read a little on how to create multiple subplots then toyed around to try and make two plots side by side for a start, but quickly realised something was wrong. I'm getting the error message "Can not reset the axes.  You are probably trying to re-use an artist in more than one Axes which is not supported"

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

def plotKappa(ax,train_kappa,test_kappa):
    objects = ('train', 'test')
    y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
    performance = [train_kappa,test_kappa]

    ax.bar(y_pos, performance, align='center', alpha=0.5)
    plt.xticks(y_pos, objects, axes=ax)
    plt.ylabel('kappa', axes=ax)
    plt.title('kappa training vs test', axes=ax)


plotKappa(ax1, 0.9 ,0.2)
plotKappa(ax2, 0.8 ,0.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as `plt.xticks(..., axes=ax)`. You probably meant to use

```
ax.set_xticks(y_pos, objects)
ax.set_ylabel('kappa')
ax.set_title('kappa training vs test')
```

instead.